# Query association to automation viewable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

Is it possible to see which automation a query activity is part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...kind of. Via the API you can access the Activity Object and search via the name of your Query to get the Program.ObjectID for each Automation. You then use the Program Object to gather the name of the Automation.

These objects are the precursor objects to Automations (Programs), but still function, unlike most of the Automation Objects that are shown in the documentation.

Pull associated Program ObjectIDs:

```
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>Activity</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Program.ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>Name</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>{{yourQueryName}}</Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
```

Gather name of Automation via Program.ObjectID:

```
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>Program</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>Description</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>ObjectID</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>{{ObjectID from other call}}</Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
```